# Facebook SDK - how to override onActivityResult() correctly?

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a simple Activity in which I want to get some information about the Facebook user:

```
public class FacebookActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_layout);

        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.
                            GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                Log.i("facebook_id", user.getId());
                                Log.i("facebook_name", user.getName());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

But `onCompleted()` method is not called if the `onActivityResult()` method is not overridden. So, my question is how to make it correctly in my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```